# Has anyone used CozyRoc SSIS+?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I work for a large Canadian retailer, and we're currently considering using CozyRoc for a large ETL project of ours. I was wondering if anyone could recommend the software, ideally through an e-mail chain or over the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use CozyRoc on our production platform and have done for about 18 months.

You may find it benificial to actually contact CozyRoc directly. They have quite a broad client base and would be able to put you in touch with a business that is using the particular features that you are interested in.

Comment: please dont close ..questions , of subjects which you know not

Comment: @pdssn: Your comment does not make sense. If you would like a reply then please clarify you comment.